# Is there a term for "shift towards zero"?

Tags: terminology, math

In pseudo code: given numbers `x` and `y`, if `x` is greater than zero, subtract the magnitude of `y` from `x`, otherwise add the magnitude of `y` to `x`. It's ok if `x` goes from being positive to negative or vice versa.

In python I've been doing this like so

```py
def shift_func(x: int, y: int) -> int:
   function = "__sub__" 
   if x <= 0:
       function = "__add__"
   return getattr(x, function)(abs(y))
```

I understand in the case were `x==0` the above function is not shifting towards zero, but that's desired in my case. My general question still stands; is there  a term for this behavior?

Comment: How about overshoot? for example, x is 3, y is 5.

Comment: If it is a rounding operation (y is strictly less than 1.0 in magnitude), there is a term "round toward zero". Other than that, I don't know any other term that will fit your description. Your current description "shift towards zero" seems fine to me.

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  Where would such a function be used?

Comment: If the function reacts always to tend towards zero (except when it is zero and must accomodate a non-zero input), then maybe the word "dampen"?

Comment: So, your calculation is... x += -1.0 * sign(x) * y ???

Comment: [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the wrong sub-forum for your question. The discipline of ***Software Engineering*** is not about math or computer programming. ***Software Engineering*** is about requirements gathering, scrums, waterfall versus spiral development, etc... Basically, software "***engineering***" involves the the least amount of engineering out of all branches of computer-related disciplines. I recommend migrating your question to either [stack exchange math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or somewhere else.

Comment: This implementation would most likely fail a peer review

Comment: Is the function being used in a discrete time step negative feedback loop? That is, similar to how a "simple harmonic function (SHM)" is computed (simulated) numerically using the spring equation, where a spring in positive displacement experiences a negative acceleration; a spring in negative displacement experiences a positive acceleration. If this is the case, the overshoot is intentional, in fact, part of the nature of SHM.

Comment: Why don’t you maintain the sign and magnitude of `x` as separate variables, and then consistently use subtraction?

Comment: To answer the various questions, the context is similar to a number line that stretches infinitely in both directions. I do not know if `x` is positive, negative, or zero.  Also, overshoot is allowed as stated in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking something like,

> I wrote some code by-hand. However, I suspect that a standard math library contains have a function like the one I wrote.
> Here is the mathematical operation I want. I do not know the name, or words, for this mathematical operation. What words are usually used to describe this mathematical operation?

### Some notes about your code:

Most programmers want code which is ***easy-to-read***.

#### Note 1

Your original code said stuff like:

```
function = "__add__"
# ... 
getattr(x, function)(abs(y))`.
```

For clarity, note that `getattr(x, "__add__")(y)` is the same as `x + y`.

`x + y` is ten times easier to understand.

All of the following are equivalent:

```
result = x + y
# --------------------------------------
result = x.__add__(y)
# --------------------------------------
result = x.getattr("__add__")(y)
# --------------------------------------
function = "__add__"
result = x.getattr(function)(y)
# --------------------------------------
```

It is almost as if you tried to make `x + y` as difficult to understand as possible.

Next time, make your code as easy to understand for another human/non-computer.
Readability matters more than:

- showing that you know how `getattr` works
- showing that you know that the addition operator is really named "`__add__`", when you look-under-the-hood.

#### Note 2

Variable names should be "self-documenting" (self-explanatory)
one-letter variables names (like `y`) are considered to be *very*  poor programming practice.

At first, I was not sure which of `x` or `y` was the change/shift and which was the number you wanted to apply the shift to.

#### Note 3

If you are going to sanitize your function inputs, the sanitization should be explicit.

When I first read your code, I had no idea why you wrote, `abs(y)` inside of the return statement.

Relatively speaking, it makes more sense to sanitize function at the ***beginning*** of the function, rather than the middle or end.

The return statement is too late to error-check input `y` and make sure that `y` is not a negative number.

Write a comment explaining that you are sanitizing the function inputs.

Cleaning-up the inputs to the function should be separated from applying/using the sanitized inputs.

In programming we want things as modular (separate from each other) as possible.

Intertwining error-checking with non-error-checking is a bad idea.

### Reworked Code

The following still needs improvement, but it is easier to understand (relatively speaking) than your original code:

```
# The variable named `shift` is named `y` in the old code
# The variable named `old_val` is named `x` in the old code

def shift_func(old_val: int, shift: int) -> int:
   # begin sanitizing inputs

   shift = abs(shift)        

   # end sanitizing inputs

   # begin actual work

   if old_val <= 0:
       return old_val + shift
   else: # `old_val` is positive
       return old_val - shift
```

### Examples of input/output

```
╔═══════════════════════╦════════╗
║ INPUTS                ║ OUTPUT ║
╠═════════════╦═════════╣        ║
║ x           ║ y       ║        ║
║ (old value) ║ (shift) ║        ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ +14         ║ +4      ║ +10    ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ -14         ║ +4      ║ -10    ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

### Question

What is supposed to happen if the shift is larger in magnitude than the starting point?

For example, we begin at `-25` and slide `47` units toward zero.

Is the result supposed to be `+22` ?

Maybe if the shift is required to always be less than the starting point? I am not sure, you might have to write some error-checking for that.

### Alternative Implementation

You could use the following approach.
I do not think it's really any better though, just different.

The jist of things is to return `x - sign(x) * y`

```
def sign(number):
    return number // abs(number)

def shift_toward_zero(old_point: int, shift: int) -> int:
    """
    shifts a number toward zero.

    Examples:

    .--------------------------------.
    | INPUTS                | OUTPUT |
    |-----------------------|        |
    |             |         |        |
    | `point`     | `shift` |        |
    |-------------+---------+--------|
    | +14         | +4      | +10    |
    |-------------+---------+--------|
    | -14         | +4      | -10    |
    *--------------------------------*
    """
    # begin  sanitizing inputs
    shift = abs(shift)
    # end sanitizing inputs

    # begin actual work
    new_point = old_point - sign(old_point) * shift
    return new_point
```

### Final Notes

I have a bachelor's degree in math, but I am not sure there is an orthodox name for this function.

Maybe, "shift toward zero"?

It is ***not*** a waste of time to write your own code to perform this operation. I guarantee that it is not built into any of the standard math libraries.

Comment: Alternatively, `shift_func = lambda old_val, shift: old_val+abs(shift)*(1 if old_val<=0 else -1)`.

Comment: While this in informative, only the last section attempts to answer my question. With regards to your question: `It's ok if x goes from being positive to negative or vice versa.`

Comment: Sure, but the literal answer to the question you asked is "No". That's not much of an answer, but you're asking for something really specific. And all the advice on your code is good.